# WatchKit: What is the difference between bundle identifier and WKAppBundleIdentifer and why can it cause App groups to not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I do not know what the purpose of `WKAppBundleIdentifier` is. Is the bundle identifier for WatchKit Extension and `WKAppBundleIdentifer` suppose have the same id? When I assign them both the same id `com.myProbjectName.watchkitextension` sharing data (App groups) between iOS simulator and iWatch simulator doesn't work at all. However, if I change my `WKAppBundleIdentifer` to `com.myProbjectName.watchkitapp` and leave the bundle identifier for WatchKit the same (`com.myProbjectName.watchkitextension`) sharing data between iOS Simulator and Apple Watch Simulator works. Why does it do this and what is the difference between `WKAppBundleIdentifier` and bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`)?

Answer (score 3):

`CFBundleIdentifier` is the Bundle Identifier of the WatchKit Extension which contains the WatchKit App inside of it. Therefore the Bundle Identifier is unique for the extension, something like `com.some.app.watchkitextension`.

`WKAppBundleIdentifier` is the identifier of the WatchKit App bundled inside the Extension. That is the reason why these values must be different since WatchKit App has its own Bundle Identifier (e.g. `com.some.app.watchkitapp`). This value should be the value of WatchKit App's `CFBundleIdentifier`.

It is also related to provisioning. All three parts (iOS app, WatchKit Extension and WatchKit App) must have their own Bundle Identifier and therefore provisioning profiles.

---

`WKAppBundleIdentifier` is actually part of the WatchKit extension's specification of WatchKit App under `NSExtension`.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.some.app.watchkitapp</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.watchkit</string>
</dict>
```